# App Engine Firewall Setup For PubSub Push Messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-cloud-pubsub

Our application is an internal application and does not need any external communication. To make this happen we have setup the default firewall rule as deny *. This does not have any impact on the Task Queues or Cron Jobs we have and they are communicating as usual. But after this change the PubSub push messages are no longer coming. I have search the google documentation for the IP addresses of the PubSub instances but nothing effective has been found so far. Has anybody faced this issue before? If yes please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Task Queues and Cron traffic will be allowed by the firewall, even
>   when the default rule is set to deny.
>   [[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#allowing_requests_from_your_services)]

Regarding PubSub IP ranges, there is no direct way to get those IPs as they are changing from time to time. You have to use `nslookup` command to get the ranges [[2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#where_can_i_find_product_name_short_ip_ranges)].